# The algorithms' captions appear in the list of abbreviations

Tags: algorithms, acronyms

I have a problem with the list of abbreviations. The problem is that the algorithms' captions appear in the list of abbreviations!

I use the `loabbrv` package for the abbreviations, and by the command `\listofabbreviations` I generate the list of abbreviations.

Inside my document, I have some algorithms written using the packages `algorithm` and `algorithmicx`. When the list of abbreviations is generated the algorithms' captions appear just in the middle of the abbreviations list!

I really appreciate your help for avoiding this problem.

Thanks a lot

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Where can we find the package `loabbrv`?